# Acessing currently logged in user in class based view

Tags: python, django, django-views

i'm trying to sort some model-data inside a class based view by the currently logged in user. How do i do that?
I tried the following, but it didnt work:

```
class ChatOverView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return [Message.objects.filter(sender=self.request.user),
                Message.objects.filter(receiver=self.request.user)]

    model = {"received": get_queryset()[0], "sent": get_queryset()[1]}
    template_name = "chat/home-chat.html"
```

Im getting the following error message: `TypeError: get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Thanks for Your Help!

**Edit**
I am aiming to implement a chat-system on my website. In order to do that, i set up a database which stores all sent messages. Each entry contains a "sender" and a "receiver" field.
With Help of this View i want to display all messages the currently logged in user received or sent.

Comment: What is this `'received'` and `'sent'` part aiming to do? This is *not* how you implement a class-based view.

Comment: Can you please first explain *what* you aim to do, instead of how you aim to do this. I have the idea that you are overcomplicating things.

Comment: I want to pass a dict to the template in order to handle the data over there. I thought i didnt want to pass the whole database-content to the template and would sort it before giving it to the template. What should i change? @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply override the `get_context_data`. You can let the Django `ListView` handle one of the lists, and handle the other one yourself:

```
class ChatOverView(ListView):
    model = Message
    context_object_name = 'sent'
    template_name = 'chat/home-chat.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            sender=self.request.user
        )

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context.update(
            received=Message.objects.filter(receiver=self.request.user)
        )
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How do i access the received messages from inside the template?

Comment: @Sarius: you iterate over the `sent` and `received` variables.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity: what would i do, if i wanted to pass n lists to the template? Would that be possible?

Comment: @Sarius: you can add more in the `context.update(name_of_var=value, ...)`.